# MS Access 2016 program pops Stack errors and Security Warnings on non-developer PCs

Tags: security, stack

I read all the rules on asking good questions here, I hope this will suffice.

I am having problems with an Access 2016 .ACCDE database.

The program runs fine on my machine. When I try to run it on my friends' machines (either the .ACCDE or .ACCDB version) it won't load and pops Out Of Stack Space errors and the Security Notice instead.

### So, here's the set up:

The program was written in Access 2016. It is a Front End/Back End design. It's not a very big program 16 tables, 41 forms and 51 code modules.

I use the FMS Access Analyzer to help make sure my code is clean so the quality of the program is good to very good.

### PRIOR versions of the program ran fine on all machines. I made several changes, improvements and moved it to the \Documents folder. Now we are having problems.

Machine 'A' (Development PC): New Win 10, 8GB RAM, Full MS Access (not runtime).

Machine 'B': Newish laptop 2GB RAM, lots of disk, Access 2016 Runtime. It ran prior versions of the program fine but now is blowing errors.

### Machine 'C': Newish desktop 8GB RAM lots of free disk, full Access (not runtime). It also ran prior versions of the program fine but now is blowing errors.

Initally, the opening form would pop an error that the On Load event caused an Out Of Stack Space event. User says, 
"Still happens after a fresh reboot.  It does NOT happen with other .accde files." Both A and B machines are showing the same errors.

I made many changes but could not cure the Out Of Stack Space error. Finally, I went to an Autoexec Macro instead of a startup form. The autoexec macro that caused Error 3709 and aborted the macro. Machine B had CPU 49%, Mem 60%. The micro sd drive had 5.79GB used and 113GB free.

I deleted the macro. Went back to startup Form, still no luck.

### I asked if he got a MS Security error, he said, "Yes, Microsoft Access Security Notice.  Figuring just a general warning since it let's me go ahead and open the file. The directory where we have the program (C:Documents\Condor) was already a Trusted Location on my work machine."

So, does this sound like a Security error? 
Is it a problem to have the program in the \Documents folder?

Answer (score 0):

okay well there's a lot going on in this post - so to sanity check I would suggest getting back to basics: working just with .accdb and full license - - does it throw any errors at all?

an aside: because with runtime an error = crash....usually it just rolls over and closes without any message.

an aside: you don't need .accde for run time as it can't affect design, only if there are full license people you want to keep from going into design view would you need accde.

you have to be sure that the runtime / accde machines have the exact same path to the back end as your full license machine's path  - as the path is stored in the front end

but sanity checking the accdb on the full license machine is the first step in debugging this... if this is not all okay then must be dealt with first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I thought I had posted that the problem was resolved.The table links broke because, as you pointed out, one person's This PC\Documents\whatever folder is different from anyone else's. (C:\Users\KentH\Documents\whatever vs. C:\Users\JohnT\Documents\whatever)

Thank you for your time and suggestions. Broken table links can cause the stack error, fer sure, and that can be caused by trying to put programs someplace other than the C:\Programs folder.

D'oh!